# Math Domain Error in QGIS Using XYZ Tiles

Tags: qgis, xyz-tiles

I've noticed similar issues with the plug in to mine but the answer given also lead to the same Math Domain Error.
I do want to be in the same projection. I have tried changing the extent to '-180.000000000,180.000000000,-89, 89 [EPSG:4326]' which was given on a previous post but it also gave the error.

What can I do to fix this:

> QGIS version: 3.32.1-Lima QGIS code revision: 4a078ecf63 Qt version:
> 5.15.3 Python version: 3.9.5 GDAL version: 3.7.1 GEOS version: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0 PROJ version: Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023 PDAL version: 2.5.5 (git-version: a7569c) Algorithm started at:
> 2023-08-01T13:02:29 Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)'
> starting… Input parameters: { 'BACKGROUND_COLOR' : QColor(0, 0, 0, 0),
> 'DPI' : 96, 'EXTENT' :
> '-11887168.949073933,-11805219.796561170,5035929.347135771,5079289.137810403 [EPSG:4326]', 'HTML_ATTRIBUTION' : '', 'HTML_OSM' : False,
> 'HTML_TITLE' : '', 'METATILESIZE' : 4, 'OUTPUT_DIRECTORY' :
> 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'OUTPUT_HTML' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'QUALITY' :
> 75, 'TILE_FORMAT' : 0, 'TILE_HEIGHT' : 256, 'TILE_WIDTH' : 256,
> 'TMS_CONVENTION' : False, 'ZOOM_MAX' : 13, 'ZOOM_MIN' : 8 }
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py",
> line 624, in processAlgorithm self.generate(writer, parameters,
> context, feedback) File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py",
> line 296, in generate metatiles = get_metatiles(self.wgs_extent, zoom,
> self.metatilesize) File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py",
> line 123, in get_metatiles right_tile, bottom_tile =
> deg2num(south_edge, east_edge, zoom) File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py",
> line 71, in deg2num ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad) + (1
> / math.cos(lat_rad))) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n) ValueError: math domain
> error
>
> Execution failed after 0.05 seconds
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)'
> finished HTML output has been generated by this algorithm. Open the
> results dialog to check it.

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/464219/2856 help?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason changing -11887168.949073933,-11805219.796561170,5035929.347135771,5079289.137810403 [EPSG:4326]'
to '-118.87,-118.05,50.35,50.79 [EPSG:4326]' has worked as I am able to run the plug-in now and have files. The issue now is the leaflet preview doesnt show the tiles. When selecting come with basemap the basemap shows just fine.